# Get PDB information for latest ServiceStack release

Tags: servicestack, pdb-files

Currently working on ServiceStack v.4.0.17 I am trying to get the `ServiceStack.pdb` file from NuGet package.

I tried to get it from [Symbol source website](http://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Metadata/NuGet/Project/ServiceStack) but the latest version available is 3.9.70
I downloaded the NuGet package from https://www.myget.org/F/servicestack/ to be able to get the very last ServiceStack version.

Attached a screenshot with symbol link paths:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried it myself, but the wiki on the github lists several sources for pdb files:

[Source Symbols](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Release-Notes#source-symbols-are-now-included-in-all-nuget-packages)

The third link is at MyGet: [MyGet PDBs](http://srv.symbolsource.org/pdb/MyGet)

Since you're pulling the packages from MyGet, you should probably look there for PDBs too. ServiceStack 3.x is in maintenance mode and won't be upgraded (except for bugfixes) so for now it seems the new versions are only posted to MyGet and not at all to NuGet.

Comment: I added a screenshot to show you my current source symbols paths.

Comment: @labilbe Did you follow the instructions provided on the Wiki (first link) to turn on source fetching in general etc? Is it still not working for you? Note that you've told VS to only load specified module (lucky for you, I understand French ;) ), second radio button choice on the screenshot, so you must then have specified ServiceStack in the window that shows when you click on "Specifier les modules"?

Comment: @labilbe Could you show us the dialog that is shown when you click on "Specifier les modules"?

Comment: @rawposer I set ServiceStack*.* and checked "Always load symbols located next to modules"

Comment: @labilbe Not sure how to proceed, but I LOLed when I saw @ raw **poser** :) Hope I'm not really a poser ;)

Comment: sorry for the mistake :) Happy you loled it for that, by the way I don't understand the joke. What's a poser?

Comment: ServiceStack is in beta now and packages are available on NuGet now. Could you try again (you can safely remove the MyGet 'references')?
Btw, a 'poser' is someone who pretends to be something (s)he is not, immitating a movement or behavior of a certain group of people. It's a derogatory term ;)

Comment: Thank you for all the explanations !